# Invoke method by reflection with dynamic parameters

Tags: java, reflection

I'm invoking some method of Class's instance using the `method.invoke(instance, args...)` way but for each method inside the `instance`, as the `invoke` Javadoc rightly points out, each argument must be manually specified.

Thinking about Spring... how it could valorize parameters in controller's method behind the hood during HTTP calls? (but surely it does in a completely different way I think...)

I wonder if there's any way in Java to dynamically pass parameters in reflection (or not even reflection) without specifying each of them singularly.

EDIT

The instance class declaration is something like:

```
public class Something {

    public void doSth(String par1, String par2, Integer par3) {
        //....
    }

    public void doSthElse(String par1, Boolean par2) {
        //....
    }

    public void doSthElseMore(Integer par1) {
        //....
    }

}
```

How I'm invoking each method:

```
...
for (Method method : instance.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    Object[] array = //BL: build array of values to pass to the invoke method.
//1. doSth may be new Object[] {"abc", "def", 123}
//2. doSthElse iteration may be new Object[] {"abc", false}
//3. doSthElseMore iteration may be new Object[] {123}
    return method.invoke(instance, array);
}
...
```

As shown above, each method inside `Something` class (`instance`) have a different number of parameters.

On each iteration, the `array` have a different number of values to pass to the `invoke`.

Comment: Spring just 1) determines the arguments to the method, 2) determines whether the arguments it has can be converted to these arguments, 3) converts the arguments and 4) invokes the method with those arguments. There is no magic, no trickery here. What specifically is your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, Boris. An example has been provided. Hope to have clarified you better what I'm trying to work out.

Comment: You can use [`Method.getParameterType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterTypes%28%29) to get the parameters to send. Based on the value you want to pass (only default value, or not), you can use a method that will create the parameters array based on that result.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Iterate over methods and invoke them all?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn yes exactly and I don't want to specify singularly each parameter on each iteration, I want to make it dynamic (if possible in Java)

Comment: If you want to call a function, you should have parameters before hand. Where will you get it? Create them randomly?

Comment: I manage to get them from an HTTP call. I have them already in an Array structure. I only have to figure how to pass them to the invoke function.

Comment: So you have parameters, and 1. you're figuring out which method should be executed and execute with given parameters or 2. You will execute all methods

Comment: Fortunately I figured out what i was missing. Actually I did not cast (or convert) each of them to the correct parameter's type. So "invoke" was always called with arrays of "String" ("123" and not 123 by instance 1) so it was not able to call the method itself with "String", "String", "Integer". So actually all I have to do now is to convert each of them to the correct type, as @Boris says in point 3, and then pass a new array of object to the invoke. Thankyou for your support, it was anyway helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually as @Boris says all I had to do to complete my job was to convert each parameters to the correct type. In this way Java managed to invoke the correct method of the `Something` class with the correct parameters types.

My project is a `Vert.x` application using `Vavr` and `jodd` but the last return statement shows how I managed to solve.

```
public Object invokeMethod(Object service, Method method, RoutingContext routingContext) throws Exception {
        MultiMap queryParams = routingContext.queryParams();
        Map<String, String> pathParams = routingContext.pathParams();
        Buffer body = routingContext.getBody();

        // 1. type, 2. name, 3. value
        List<Tuple3<Class<?>, String, Object>> list = List.empty();

        for (Parameter par : method.getParameters()) {
            ParamQuery paramQuery = par.getAnnotation(ParamQuery.class);
            if (paramQuery != null) {
                list = list.push(new Tuple3<Class<?>, String, Object>(par.getType(), paramQuery.value(),
                        queryParams.get(paramQuery.value())));
            }
        }

// TypeConverterManager used to "covnert" each object (String) from the HTTP call to the correct data type
        return method.invoke(service, list.reverse()
                .map(mapper -> TypeConverterManager.lookup(mapper._1()).convert(mapper._3())).toJavaArray());
    }
```

However, this project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/grimimirg/dungeoncave-be.git)

Answer (score 1):

Since I notice you are using an `Integer` instead of a `int` (so no primitives parameters in your examples), you can send `null` to all your methods without any problems.

So you can create an array of the correct length and this will work in your case.

```
public static Object[] getParametersArray(Parameter[] param){
    Object[] array = new Object[param.length];
    // create default primitive values based on param[#].getType()
    return array;
}
```

Then, all you have to do is to iterate the method:

```
Labo l = new Labo();
for(Method m : Labo.class.getDeclaredMethods()){
    if((m.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) > 0){
        System.out.println("SKIP " + m.getName());
        continue;
    }
    try {
        m.invoke(l, getParametersArray(m.getParameters()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Notice the skipped static method, mostly because if you run this in the method containing the `main` method, you will have a recursive call.

This was tested with :

```
public void test(String s){
    System.out.println("test String " + s);
}

public void test2(String s1, String s2){
    System.out.println("test String " + s1 + " | String " + s2);
}

public void test(Integer s){
    System.out.println("test Integer " + s);
}
```

> SKIP main
>   test String null
>   test Integer null
>   SKIP getParametersArray
>   test String null | String null

Note : If you need to manage some primitive values, you will need to get the type of the parameter to provide a default value instead of null